# Is it possible to repair sd card?

Tags: partitioning, mount, sd-card, micro-sd

I have done pretty much everything I guess. I just want to format my micro-SD card so I can write a Raspbian image to it for my RPI. To begin with I am pretty new at Ubuntu so I am pretty sure that I probably did something that "destroyed" my micro-SD.

These are the commands I used:

```
sudo -i
umount /dev/mmcblk0p1
dd bs=4M if=2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie.img of=/dev/mmcblk0
```

After 24+ hours I got impatient and just closed the terminal (I know now that this was probably not the smartest thing to do... and this is probably what destroyed my SD-card)

1. I tried using `disks` but it gives me an I/O error...
2. I tried using `gparted` but right after creating the FAT32 system, `gparted` just keeps searching and nothing happens...
3. I tried using `testdisk` but with no luck...
4. I have tried using `fdisk` but with no luck...
5. I have not yet tried on a different OS and I do not know if that would even work

Dmesg output:

```
dmesg|tail:
[   87.292298] mmcblk0: error -110 transferring data, sector 2, nr 6, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
[   87.292305] end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 2
[   87.293240] mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 3, nr 5, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
[   87.293245] end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 3
[   87.294110] mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 4, nr 4, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
[   87.294115] end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 4
[   87.296545] Buffer I/O error on device mmcblk0, logical block 0
[   87.297431] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[   87.297437] Dev mmcblk0: unable to read RDB block 0
[   87.298347]  mmcblk0: unable to read partition table
```

The output to `fdisk – l`:

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 7746 MB, 7746879488 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 236416 cylinders, total 15130624 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mmcblk0 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

I know there are no valid partitions and that happened after I tried:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=512
```

*I just want to know if it is even possible to repair my micro-SD card?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a different card reader or checking possibilities of it being some other device? (Yes, I know I should use comments, but I can't)

Comment: I have not tried using another card reader. I am using the one that are integrated in my laptop. I am not sure what you mean by "it being some other device"?  I am 100% sure that /dev/mmcblk0 is my sd card if that is what you meant.

Comment: @OneFiveZero Try another card reader, integrated ones are usually junk. And I did mean it might be something else in `/dev`.

Comment: Okay I will try formatting it on my friend's laptop with windows and his card reader. If that does not work either I will buy new card reader and probably a new micro sd card.

Comment: @OneFiveZero Okay

Comment: Well I have just tried my friends laptop with his card reader and in 20 min I had formatted and installed raspbian on my rpi and it works great. Thank you for your help.